# how to split "21-13,20-21" -> [[21,13],[20,21]] in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have already tried:

```
players = ["P. V. Sindhu","Kim H-m","Cheung N Y","S Nehwal","S Jaquet","Nozomi Okuhara"]

match_details_combined = [{'Winner':'P. V. Sindhu','Loser':'Kim H-m','Matches':'21-16,21-14'},{'Winner':'P. V. Sindhu','Loser':'Cheung N Y','Matches':'19-21,23-21,21-17'},{'Winner':'S Nehwal','Loser':'S Jaquet','Matches':'21-11,21-12'},{'Winner':'Nozomi Okuhara','Loser':'S Nehwal','Matches':'12-21,21-17,21-10'},{'Winner':'Nozomi Okuhara','Loser':'P. V. Sindhu','Matches':'21-19,20-22,22-20'}]
print(match_details_combined)

player_details = {'P. V. Sindhu':{"SW":0,"SL":0,"GW":0,"GL":0},'Kim H-m':{'SW':0,'SL':0,'GW':0,'GL':0},'Cheung N Y':{'SW':0,'SL':0,'GW':0,'GL':0},'S Nehwal':{'SW':0,'SL':0,'GW':0,'GL':0},'S Jaquet':{'SW':0,'SL':0,'GW':0,'GL':0},'Nozomi Okuhara':{'SW':0,'SL':0,'GW':0,'GL':0}}
print(player_details)

for match in match_details_combined:
    player_details[match['Winner']]['GW'] += 1
print(player_details)

for match in match_details_combined:
    player_details[match['Loser']]['GL'] += 1
print(player_details)
```

My question is :

Split the value "Matches" in match_details into a list of separate matches. 
It should look something like this :

```
"21-13,20-21" -> [[21,13],[20,21]]
```

Make sure when you split, that the resultant numbers are integers (use type casting)

Comment: matches_up = []
for m in range(len(match_details_combined)):
    matches_up.append(match_details_combined[m]['Matches'])
print(matches_up)

matches_up1 = []
for x in range(len(matches_up)):
    print(matches_up[x].split(","))
    for y in range(len(matches_up[x])):
        matches_up1.append(matches_up[x][y].split("-"))

print(matches_up1)

Answer (score 1):

Use a list of comprehension:

```
string = "21-13,20-21" 
print([[int(y) for y in x.split('-')] for x in string.split(',')])
```

output:

> [[21, 13], [20, 21]]

Comment: Please help me with this:

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.